# StackExchange API tag synonyms returns tags that do not exist on Stack Overflow

Tags: resultset, stackexchange-api

I am trying to build a taxonomy-like relationship graph for Stack Overflow tags. I extracted all tags and nearly ~37000 of those wikis. Before determining the relationships based on wikis, I decided to take look at what Stack Overflow `/tags/{tag}/synonyms` has to offer. Some of the `from_tag`s in the results are not actual tags in Stack Overflow. I thought I might have missed those in my dataset. So tried to search those with the `/tags/{tag}/info`, which however returned the information for `to_tag`.

For example:

```
{
  "creation_date": 1377674210,
  "last_applied_date": 1602368899,
  "applied_count": 1172,
  "to_tag": "java",
  "from_tag": "jre"
}
```

Is one of the results for `tags/java/synonyms` endpoint. However, there is no tag [jre](/questions/tagged/jre). If search `/tag/jre/info` I get information for Java instead.

I am confused about this behavior. How does `tags/java/synonyms` get a tag which is not a Stack Overflow tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API results are correct. As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Active&search=jre), [jre](/questions/tagged/jre) exists and was synonymised and merged with Java. In addition, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jre redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java (the page doesn't return a 404!). Apparently, you can only find tags that have been synonymised via the `/tags/{tag}/synonyms`. Thus, this route is not *that* useful for your task.

For more information, see: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718)